# Ideas for a Political Power Struggle

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I need suggestions of good ideas to help in this beginning of a political power struggle as well as a formation of a nation.

**Here is the story of the campaign that I am in:**
The party started the campaign as slaves being taken to a northern frozen wastes outpost. In said outpost there are 2000 guards and 10000 malnourished slaves. The slaves are fed on cannibalism of dead slaves. Very quickly we poison the guards food supply and simultaneously begin a slave revolt, slaves win and we have now 3000 slaves in a city with little food.

So that's the base scenario. I'm playing a lawful Good character another member of the party is Chaotic Evil (We'll call him G), but slowly turning Lawful Evil and the third party member who possesses no political sway.

So, we've decided to form a government of 30 prominent free people with a vote system to decided on matters. We meet once a week (10 days). The next slave ship with large numbers of food will arrive in about a month (10 weeks) so we suspect we have to make the food last about 80 odd days, we only have enough to feed everyone for 30ish.

We've decided to take over the slave ship when it arrives and then make it our trade ship and send it out again to trade gold from the gold mines for food.

Now heres my struggle. 'G' is gaining power steadily by using his intellect to make friends and allies and propose good ideas as a driving force behind the council. The problem is that if he gains too much sway by proposing all the good ideas then he will form himself a dictatorship.

So what i need are good method to help win over the council politically, I need to keep the people as happy as possible, find some method for getting food so 1/3 of the population don't starve (Btw, we have casters making as much food as they can)
I Don't want to gain power for myself, merely prevent G from having all the power of this new nation we are forming.

Ideally all members of the council would be equally powerful or at least someone who i thought was in similar alignment to me and also easily influenced was in power.

(Sorry for the long post, its important to me)

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour] and the [help]; they're a useful introduction to the site. In particular, Stack Exchange isn't a forum, it's a Q&A site, and the format doesn't really work for questions like this where every answer could be equally right, so I suspect this question will get put on hold soon. However, once you have 20+ rep, feel free to join the [chat]: it's better set up for campaign brainstorming.

Comment: Hi @Joe, we do generally just focus on questions that have specific possibly-correct answers, and open-ended discussions don't work well here. (This site has its niche it handles well and it sucks at most other things, discussion is the main thing it sucks at.) Maybe an RPG forum like RPG.net or EN World will suit you better for working out a solution.

Comment: Minmaxboards is a good place for asking this sort of question. Perhaps the best place.